# Can't get proprely amount of Users in API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When i use personal reports in Google Analytics i see different numbers of users in the report than when i get them with API.

Support of GA answered, that this is ok, because system use different ways to count users in report when i use GA and in data which i got from API.

Is there any way to get same number of users by API, which i can see on site of GA in my personal report? Because now, when i try to get users with API for same period and with same dimensions i get different number of users, than i can see in personal report on GA site.

Comment: Have you checked wether your api report has a different time-stamp and time-zone setting than your manual report?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  We cant help you unless we can see that and the data you are trying to compare it to.

Comment: I'm actually do not use any code for API request right now. I do my requests 
through google developers instrument. Do you need some more information from me, for better understandings my problem?